# How to ignore routing error when adding invalid vehicle on SUMO?

Tags: sumo

I am using SUMO 0.29.0 (the newest version on Macports) to create a simulation. I added `<param key="has.rerouting.device" value="true"/>` to vehicle definition so vehicles can find route by themselves.

But every once in while I face an invalid trip where start position doesn’t connect to destination. The error cause the simulation to stop with error:

> Error: Vehicle 'kglh5Owzt3e7EVaAOs54.go_to_restaurant.0U5IJqaqBP' has
> no valid route. No connection between edge '-165742422' and edge
>
> '19845843#4'. Quitting (on error).

Is there any way for me to ignore the invalid trip and continue the simulation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can start sumo with `--ignore-route-errors` but this may lead to your vehicle stopping infinitely at the end of the first edge.